# Distributed ReadWrite Lock in Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

Looking for Distributed Reentrant ReadWrite Lock solution within Hazelcast. Does anyone know if its implemented or in the works ?

Found older thread referencing this, but no solution there:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/hazelcast/readwrite/hazelcast/YBQtgHPMdP0/xwoTYdu_Z58J

Answer (score 3):

Hazelcast does not implement ReadWrite locks, and for good reason. I did try implement my own readwrite lock as suggested but its far too complicated.

The result was a readwrite lock that required too many network calls (lose performance). And still did not cater for node failures (if using multiple node)

the problem stems from the fact that you need to use semaphores for read lock (since traditional locks can only be unlocked by the thread that locked them). The issue with this is that when a node fails all of its locks will be release but the semaphores will not be released and therefore a deadlock is created.

We had several people working on this. And the issue mentioned was only the tip of the iceberg.
If anyone did find a solution, please do share, but I dont think this is a feasible problem to solve since possible solutions loose performance and and far to complex.

Comment: Interesting point about complexity. Initially I thought of a naive way of maintaining two maps(Write,Read). Write is exclusive while in Read map you keep track of number of readers. But performance would be an issue, clean up read count is also required if readers stop abruptly.

Comment: Pratically you would need to have some form of entity keeping record of all the read locks, in case of a node failure. Which would be impractically impossible to maintain efficiently since we are predicting a node failure, thus you would need such entry to be synchronized across all nodes. (Other solution would be to create a single point of failure ...)

Comment: If you do find a better solution please leave a comment here. Otherwise you can simply accept the answer :)

Comment: Which version of Hazelcast are you using? Hazelcast 3 semaphore will automatically release all acquired permits on member failure.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't implemented; but if you really need it you can build it on top of the hazelcast lower level infrastructure that is exposed through the spi.

Answer (score -1):

this seems like a decent solution to the problem: https://github.com/ThoughtWire/hazelcast-locks

It implements the java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock interface in a distributed way using Hazelcast.  It is a bit complicated to describe, but looking through the source is understandable.  Deserves a review.

Comment: not really sure what else to say about it.  I could explain the details, but the source already does that!